# android:state_enabled="false" doesnt work

Tags: android, view, selector, state

This is my selector:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_delete" 
     android:state_enabled="false"
     android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
     android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/modosprepara"
     android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_selected="false" />
    </selector>
```

"arrow_up_float" and "modosprepara" works but "ic_delete" never appears.

I use this to disable this view:

```
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(index).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: is state_selected=false?

Comment: yes!
is state_enabled wich not working

Comment: I had a similar Problem long time ago, and it turned out that the order of the states is important. By switching the order, it worked. So, try to switch state_selected to the first statement, maybe it helps.

Comment: I've tried many ways, many orders, but nothing ... not working :/
I think that it not recognize the state (enable or disable) of the view...

Comment: Thanks @Opiatefuchs. Stupid android...

Answer (score 3):

You must have to follow the order.

1) state_enabled = true

2) state_enabled = false

3) state_pressed = true

4) state_pressed = false

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/modosprepara"
     android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
     android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
    </selector>
```

and

```
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(index).setEnabled(false);
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(index).setActivated(false);
```

Thanks for the answers !